# What redirect URL we need to set to get google app oAuth token in salesforce apex?

Tags: apex, visualforce, oauth2, url, google-apps

Is there any way to put some static OR intermediate redirect URL for the google app redirect URL instead of this (https://ap1.salesforce.com/apex/GoogleAuth) hardcoded salesforce VF page URL.

We are building appexchange app where a user needs to go through this oauth process and we are facing issue with redirect url as every salesforce instance has their own URL

Any idea? How we can handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the generic endpoints:

```
https://login.salesforce.com/apex/GoogleAuth
https://test.salesforce.com/apex/GoogleAuth
```

If the user is logged in, it will take them to their most recent session. If not, they will be prompted to log in.

Comment: I have tried this but it always takes to the login screen. Any other option do you think we can do?

Comment: @SagarThoriya If they're logged in, it shouldn't do that.

Comment: Yes user is logged in... Unfortunately it doesn’t work for me. Do you think my domain would be the issue here? I have enabled my domain and I am accessing the vf page from lightning experience